# Change header image size

Tags: images, css, headers

I have a header image which looks great on desktop, however, when accessing the site on a mobile device, the image gets cut off in the middle.

How can I make it that the image automatically rescales when accessing the page on a mobile device, so that its width matches the width of the screen.

I have tried adding the following CSS code, but somehow, it doesnt seem to reference to the header image:

```
header-showcase {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the link to the site I am working on:
http://www.mathiasprobst.com

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these codes:

```
.header-showcase img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I added this code; unfortunately the problem persists.
When opening on a mobile device, the header image is still too large and gets cut off in the middle.